# API Gateway - Endpoint request timed out Randomly

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have the following flow :

[image]

My Job Lambda calls the API gateway to get the logs of my job.
The API Gateway is backed by one Master Lambda which calls the other two Lambda (Read or Write ) on the basis of parameters given.
These reading and writing are done on DynamoDB tables.
This solution was working fine for last 2 months, but since the past one week I am observing an abnormal behaviour, there is a huge increase in 5XX and 4xx errors and I am also getting major of them as  `'Endpoint request timed out'`. I am not able to understand what suddenly changed to cause this. What is the root cause for this abnormal behaviour, because sometimes it is getting executed correctly and sometimes not.
All Lambdas are deployed in Private Subnets.
The Security Group for all of them contains nothing in inbound and all destination for outbound.
The Private Subnets contain NAT Gateway.
I understand ideally I should be using VPC endpoints for DynamoDB and API Gateway, but I missed that initially.

Comment: That may be an AWS issue - sometimes the instances backing up lambda get sour, but nobody at AWS notices. The only option is to open a support ticket with AWS.

Comment: In Cloudwatch, try to find `timedout` keyword in each Lambda functions log, maybe you can get more information.

Comment: I believe the Lambda was in VPC and in a private subnet, there were not enough IP's available. I am not sure about this. I tried to get metrics from CloudWatch to check how many Lambdas were triggered at a particular time but I am not able to get a dashboard which is clear enough to detect the counts and Lambda. Is there a way where I can get the Lambda Execution metrics at Subnet Level. I hope this will help to debug more. Now I have changed the configuration to `NO VPC`, but I am not sure why this I did not face in the previous months since my Lambdas are running at the same frequency.